# How can I alert the user after a long running process has finished?

Tags: c#, winforms, alerts

I'm looking for some ideas for alerting a user when a long running process has completed from a winforms application. The process could take a couple minutes or a couple hours depending on their inputs, and more than likely they'll just minimize the application and work on something else in the meantime. I know I can do something like playing a windows sound like this:

```
System.Media.SystemSounds.Exclamation.Play();
```

But most users here in the office don't have speakers so I don't think it would be very effective.

What are some other techniques I could do to tell the user, "Wake up!!! Your data is ready for you, finally!!!!"

Thanks!

Comment: What wrong with  MessageBox.Show("Wake up!!! Your data is ready for you, finally!!!!")?

Comment: You should wuphf them http://wuphf.com/ (from the office)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some ideas:

- Animated or changed system tray icon
- "Toaster" popup from the system tray (like Outlook, messenger, or some AV apps use)
- Blinking alert in taskbar
- Send an e-mail
- Play a sound/audio alert
- Message box
- Have an indicator in the status bar at the bottom of your app

Of these, I like the system tray icon + toaster pop up the best.  Blinking alert in the taskbar is too demanding, e-mail has too much latency and requires too much configuration, audio alerts have the issues you mentioned in the question, message box blocks execution of it's thread, and a status bar indicator is too subtle.

Comment: awarded for the most complete answer. I ended up incorporating a few of them including the sound, notifyIcon, and the window flash. Can I keep the balloon open until a user clicks it, i.e. prevent it from fading away?

Answer (score 2):

**This sounds like an ideal use case for a notification in the taskbar's [Notification Area](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511448.aspx).**

This has the advantage of alerting the user immediately without relying on things like sound that may or may not be available on the user's computer and without the invasiveness of a message box.

[image: Notification sample]

...except you might say "Process completed" instead :-)

Answer (score 1):

Open a Message Box.. if the app is minimized it will flash on the start bar.

Comment: maybe call MessageBox.Show() on a different thread when needed? remember to call it as MessageBox.Show(this,message);

Answer (score 1):

How about blinking the form in the taskbar similar to how most IM programs blink when a new message is received. You'll need to P/Invoke to get that functionality, but it's actually very easy:

http://pietschsoft.com/post/2009/01/26/CSharp-Flash-Window-in-Taskbar-via-Win32-FlashWindowEx.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You don't need speakers to do the [console beep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.beep.aspx)...

`Console.Beep();`

Answer (score 0):

You can allow the user to customise how they want to be notified if you've got the dev. time.